# Full screen background image with max-width

Tags: css

I'm using the first technique described [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) to create a "full screen" background image that scales proportionally with the browser.

My CSS for the image container is:

```
.fs-img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 4.5em;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

However I'd like to set a `max-width` on the my site of 1200px. Of course applying this to the body element has no impact on the image due to it being `position: fixed`.

So is there an alternative way of having a full screen image with a maximum width while still maintaining fixed to the bottom?

Here's the [demo](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8063263/fullscreen/index.htm) site I'm testing with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want using the following styles:

```
.fs-img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 4.5em;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin:0 -600px;
    background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LqGkj/)

Comment: left and righ 50% and negative half of the overall width margins = smart ;)